# Scrollable Foundation Section headers

Tags: zurb-foundation

Looking through http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html, is there anyway I can add horizontal scroll for Section headers ( Tabs) .  I am looking something like http://www.seyfertdesign.com/jquery/ui.tabs.paging.html in foundation sections with horizontal scroll and continue to use accordion in small screen

Comment: This is controlled by javascript.. What have you tried ?

Comment: Never really worked on that

Comment: Sorry about the late answer submission was on holidays!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for those interested : https://codepen.io/gdyrrahitis/pen/BKyKGe

```
.tabs {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  .tabs-title {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if someone needs an angularjs with jquery implementation, below code can help you, for pure jquery replace angularjs directive method with a native js method with respective attributes.

I tried to search for similar implementation but found nothing, so I have written a simple angular directive which can transform a foundation CSS tabs to scrollable tabs

```
angular.module("app.directives.scrollingTabs", [])
.directive("scrollingTabs", ScrollingTabsDirective);
//@ngInject
function ScrollingTabsDirective($timeout, $window) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    if(attr.scrollingTabs == "true"){
      element.addClass('scrolling-tabs-container');
      element.find('.nav-buttons').remove();
      element.append('<div class="scrolling-tabs nav-buttons nav-buttons-left"></div>');
      element.append('<div class="scrolling-tabs nav-buttons nav-buttons-right"></div>');

      let scrolledDiv = $(element).find('.tabs');
      let scrolled;
      let scrolling;

      let scrollFn = (step, animationTime, cb) => {
        scrolled = Math.max(scrolled + step, 0);
        scrolledDiv.animate({
          scrollLeft:  scrolled
        }, animationTime, ()=>{
          if (scrolling) {
            scrollFn(step, animationTime, cb)
          }else{
            if(cb){cb()}
          }
        });
      };

      let checkActiveNavButtonsClasses = () => {
        scrolled = scrolledDiv.scrollLeft();
        let scrollWidth = scrolledDiv.get(0).scrollWidth;
        let scrolledDivWidth = scrolledDiv.get(0).clientWidth;

        if(scrollWidth > scrolledDivWidth){
          element.addClass('nav-active');
          scrollWidth = scrolledDiv.get(0).scrollWidth;
          if(scrolled == 0){
            element.removeClass('nav-active-left').addClass('nav-active-right')
          }else if(scrolled > 0 && scrolled + scrollWidth < scrolledDivWidth){
            element.addClass('nav-active-left').addClass('nav-active-right');
          }else if(scrolled > 0 && scrolled + scrollWidth >= scrolledDivWidth){
            element.addClass('nav-active-left').removeClass('nav-active-right');
          }else{
            element.removeClass('nav-active-left').removeClass('nav-active-right')
          }
        }else{
          element.removeClass('nav-active-left').removeClass('nav-active-right').removeClass('nav-active');
        }
      };

      let scrollToActiveTab = () => {
        let activeDD = scrolledDiv.find('dd.active');
        let tabsOffset = scrolledDiv.offset();
        let activeTaboffset = activeDD.offset();
        let activeTabwidth = activeDD.width();
        let scrolledStep = activeTaboffset.left - tabsOffset.left - scrolledDiv.width() + activeTabwidth;

        scrollFn(scrolledStep, 100, checkActiveNavButtonsClasses);
      };

      element.find(".nav-buttons.nav-buttons-left")
        .off("click.scrolling")
        .on("click.scrolling", (event)=>{
          event.preventDefault();
          scrolling = false;
          scrollFn(-100, 100, checkActiveNavButtonsClasses);
        })
        .off("mouseover.scrolling")
        .on("mouseover.scrolling", function (event) {
          scrolling = true;
          scrollFn(-2, 1, checkActiveNavButtonsClasses);
        })
        .off("mouseout.scrolling")
        .on("mouseout.scrolling", function (event) {
          scrolling = false;
        });

      element.find(".nav-buttons.nav-buttons-right")
        .off("click.scrolling")
        .on("click.scrolling", (event)=>{
          event.preventDefault();
          scrolling = false;
          scrollFn(100, 100, checkActiveNavButtonsClasses);
        })
        .off("mouseover.scrolling")
        .on("mouseover.scrolling", function (event) {
          scrolling = true;
          scrollFn(2, 1, checkActiveNavButtonsClasses);
        })
        .off("mouseout.scrolling")
        .on("mouseout.scrolling", function (event) {
          scrolling = false;
        });

      $timeout(()=>{
        checkActiveNavButtonsClasses();
        scrollToActiveTab()
      },1000);

      $($window).off('resize.scrolling').on('resize.scrolling', _.debounce(()=> {
        checkActiveNavButtonsClasses();
      }, 500));

      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $($window).off('resize.scrolling');
      });
    }
  }
}}
```

css:

```
.scrolling-tabs-container {
position: relative;
.tabs {
overflow-x: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
display: block;
margin-right: 18px;

dd {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0px -3px 0px 0px;

}

.tabs-title {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
}
.scrolling-tabs {
&.nav-buttons {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 19px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  top: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    &:before {
      color: #444;
    }
  }
  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 7px;
    top: 8px;
    color: #777;
  }
  &.nav-buttons-left {
    left: 0;
    &:before {
      content: '<';
    }
  }
  &.nav-buttons-right {
    right: 18px;
    &:before {
      content: '>';
    }
  }
}
}
&.nav-active{
.tabs{
  margin-right: 36px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}
.scrolling-tabs {
  &.nav-buttons {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}
}
&.nav-active-left{
.scrolling-tabs{
  &.nav-buttons-left{
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
}
}
&.nav-active-right{
.scrolling-tabs{
  &.nav-buttons-right{
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
}}}
```

HTML: Foundation Tabs template.

```
<tabset class="list-tabs" scrolling-tabs="true">
    <tab heading="tab1"></tab>
    <tab heading="tab2"></tab>
   <tab heading="tab2"></tab>
</tabset>
```

Answer (score -1):

Before you start you'll want to verify that both jQuery (or Zepto) and foundation.js are available on your page. These come with foundation package so just uncomment them in your footer or include them accordingly.

```
<div class="section-container auto" data-section>
  <section class="active">
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel1">Section 1</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 1.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel2">Section 2</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

The foundation documentation has all of the information for this :

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html#panel2

This will get you your section tabular headers. You then want to manage the content to be scrollable.

```
<div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 1.</p>
    </div>
```

This content here will be the area to work on, try adding a new class called `.scrollable`

Within this class use something like:

```
.scrollable{
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

You may want to add some more to this however this will get you started. Your HTML should now look like this  :

```
<div class="content scrollable" data-section-content>
  <p>Content of section 1. This content will be scrollable when the content has exceeded that of the div size. </p>
</div>
```

This this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am looking for scrollable headers not the content of the tab. Please look at examples in  http://www.seyfertdesign.com/jquery/ui.tabs.paging.html ( scrollable headers )